# Script task in SSIS Package

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ssis

I have recently upgraded my SSIS package from 2015 to 2017.In one such package a script task is present in which after deployment if opened in visual studio 2017 an warning pop up `FOUND SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES 2012 SCRIPT TASK <SCRIPT TASK NAME> REQUIRES MIGRATION`. What is the exact cause of this warning? Have executed the package and it works properly through SSDT and job.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the issue so I'll just add a comment instead of an answer and leave that open for someone else with more knowledge, but in my googling, it appears it could be a common bug?

I found mention here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36581382/ssis-script-task-error-found-sql-server-integration-services-2012-script-task

With a proposed solution.

Comment: I have read about this method but cant change the script task into exe without proper prior knowledge

Comment: Could be a .net version change or some other .dll version change in the script task, you just need to open it and save it again to recompile it and should be good.

Comment: @Brad but the .net version shouldn't change if I have created the package in my remote server and checked it after the deployment?

Comment: like Brad said. all you have to do is open the script task and close it. it will do the migration and the problem goes away.